# Python: Why doesn't my program print anything?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I use print() only, it'll print the spelling of the number in the range of 0-1000, but I'd like to save the result as a variable with return() to assign it to other functions later. When I test it, it does not print any thing out with return(), where is the problem? Thanks!

update: it turned out I called return() before print(), so print() would never get called; but then I switched their position, it still doesn't work, why? Thanks.

```
def spell(Numbers):
    result = []

    def spellOne(Numbers):





    print (result)
    return(result)

    spellOne(number)
```

Comment: ... Because you return before you print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you need to call `spellOne(number)` before you print or even return the results so that the second function works. Because when you call `spell` all it will do is print `result` which is an empty list. Then it will return it and not even get to the next line. With the way it was before the second function will never get called unless you put it before.

```
spellOne(number)
print (result)
return(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your indentation, it would appear that this is because you call return before calling print - in other words print never gets called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Based on your suggestion, I switched the position of return() and print(), but it gives a pair of square brackets continuing nothing. I have no idea why this happened.